# CkeckedListBox and Datatable to select one or more columns Vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

Can Any one help to figure out a code in Vb.net, to retrieve one or more columns from datatable based on a checkedlistbox.
for instance,

### I have this table with the following column name

### Col1   Col2    col3    col4    Coln

### v.11   v.12     v13     v14     v1n

### v.11   v.12     v13     v14     v1n

### v.11   v.12     v13     v14     v1n

lets assume I checked col1 and col4, I would like to code to retrieve these two columns or more depending on how many items were checked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the code running however, I will appreciate it if someone could help find more shorter and efficient code thanks 
herein attached is my code:

Dim table2 As New DataTable() ' display the data in the datagridview
        Dim citem As String           ' to read the checkedboxlist to create columns in table2
        Dim table3 As New DataTable() ' to retrieve values from the checkedboxlist for the rows

```
    table2.Columns.Add("Risk Factors") ' create a common column between the different datatables (like ID)
    For Each citem In Crlist.CheckedItems
        table2.Columns.Add(citem)
    Next
    Dim rfselected As New List(Of String)
    Dim cselected As New List(Of String)
    Dim tblfiltered As New DataTable()
    For Each item In RfLst.CheckedItems
        rfselected.Add(String.Format("'{0}'", item))
    Next

    If rfselected.Count <> 0 Then
        Dim rows = atable.Select(String.Format("`Risk Factors` IN ({0})", String.Join(",", rfselected))) 'retrieve the rows from the orginal data called atable
        If rows.Length <> 0 Then
            table3 = rows.CopyToDataTable
        End If
    End If
    For Each dr As DataRow In table3.Rows
        table2.ImportRow(dr)
    Next
    DataGridView2.DataSource = table2
```